# How to create multiple Lists at runtime?

Tags: c#, nested-lists

I'll explain briefly what I'm doing. I'm doing a program that lets me drag and drop PictureBoxes from a listview to a panel. There I can move them freely or remove them from the panel, but what I'm trying to do now is, when the user makes a selection box around the PictureBoxes and click a button, it will create an ID of those PictureBoxes.

*Example* -I selected 3 PictureBoxes, each PictureBox has its own name, then when I right click and click a button from the toolstrip it should create an ID of those 3 PictureBoxes like "M0".

***Code below***

I have a nested list that holds PictureBox as his type. I want to create a new list to add to the nested list with a button click.

```
List<List<PictureBox>> listaAgrupamentos = new List<List<PictureBox>>();
List<PictureBox> groupObjects = new List<PictureBox>();
```

When I press one button, I add individually PictureBoxes that I selected into **groupObjects List**

```
     private void agruparToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //hoverObject 
       //This object is to identify which PictureBox I hover

       //startLocation and EndLocation
       //This variables are to tell me the location of the selection box

        if (hoverObject.Location.X > startLocation.X && hoverObject.Location.Y > startLocation.Y &&
            hoverObject.Location.X < endLocation.X && hoverObject.Location.Y < endLocation.Y)
        {
            hoverObject.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

            groupObjects.Add(hoverObject);

        }
        

    }
```

Then when I finished adding my desired PictureBoxes to the list, I click another button to add **groupObject List** to the **listaAgrupamentos Nested List**

```
        private void confirmarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        listaAgrupamentos.Add(groupObjects);

    }
```

Now I want constantly create dynamic list each time i press the **confirmarToolStripMenuItem_Click** with different ID's but I'm stuck for hours figuring out.

***Visual Representation***

First I can do this
[image]

But then I want to do this, but I can't because I need to create another List to add to the nested list because **groupObjects List** it's already populated with data.
[image]

Comment: The actual question, " I want constantly create dynamic list each time i press the confirmarToolStripMenuItem_Click with different ID", is not very clear. What do you mean with dynamic lists? Lists of what?

Comment: @JonasH I don't know how to specifically explain with words so I put some images to try to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you simply want to create a new list when you have added the current list to the "nested list". I.e.

```
private void confirmarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listaAgrupamentos.Add(groupObjects);
    groupObjects = new List<PictureBox>();
}
```

That way the existing list is frozen, and any new objects added to `groupObjects` will be placed in a separate list.

Comment: Wow, was that simple XD,